# Code explanation of a function

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am given a code and i need to explain it. Unfortunately i don't understand a few lines of the program and i am finding it hard to explain it. I would greatly appreciate if someone can help me out to explain the code better and also explain the parts that i did not include in my explanation. These are the parts of the program that i am finding it hard to explain:

```
 return (array[n] + total(array,n-1));
```

and

```
(array[n] == 1) ?
```

This is my try towards explaining the code:

> A function named total is defined before the main function containing
>   an array of 14 objects and an integer n as it’s parameters. The code
>   in the function includes an if loop, if n is equal to 0, array will
>   return 0 objects. Otherwise return array of n objects added with the
>   total. In the main function, an array containing 14 objects is
>   defined. Sum, n and cattotal are all defined as integers. The sum is
>   set to the total. A for loop is used to get the information from the
>   array and print how many cats there are per bus stop. Recursion is
>   used for the loop to keep repeating until the array is run out of
>   objects, that is 14 objects. The bus stop total is printed all along
>   the way until it reaches the final stop. At the end, the total amount
>   of cats seen is also printed.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int total(int array[14], int n)
{

    if (n == 0) {
        return array[0];
    }

    return (array[n] + total(array,n-1));
}

int main(void)
{
    int array[14] = {5,1,3,2,3,7,0,1,0,1,4,0,2,1}; //array storing 14 objects
    int sum, n;
    int cattotal = 0;

    sum = total(array,13);

    for (n=0; n < 14; n++){

    (array[n] == 1) ?

    printf("Bus stop #%d : %d cat\n",(n+1),array[n]):

    printf("Bus stop #%d : %d cats\n",(n+1),array[n]);

    cattotal += array[n];

    printf("Bus stop#%d total: %d cats\n\n)",(n+1),cattotal);
    }

    printf("\nTotal amount of cats seen: %d\n",sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First you have recursion. You call the function inside itself with the 2nd parameter reduced by 1 until you call it with the 2nd parameter being 0 `if ( n == 0).` Fort the `(array[n] == 1) ?` you should read what the ternary operator is.

Comment: Please clarify - you want us to create/review documentation for a program that is not yours?

Comment: The recursive `total` function is weird. It takes as `n` one less than the array dimension and has a base case wich doesn't correspond to the empty array, but to an array with a single element.

Comment: @MartinJames sounds more like homework. that's why i only gave hints instead of completely explaining it. But guess there are to many that just answer anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(array[n] == 1) ?

   printf("Bus stop #%d : %d cat\n",(n+1),array[n]):

   printf("Bus stop #%d : %d cats\n",(n+1),array[n]);
```

is a weird way to write:

```
if ((array[n] == 1)
  printf("Bus stop #%d : %d cat\n",(n+1),array[n]);
else
  printf("Bus stop #%d : %d cats\n",(n+1),array[n]);
```

using a "conditional expression".

---

```
(array[n] + total(array,n-1));
```

is recursive call of the `total` function.

The `total` function computes the sum of the `n` first elements in a given array.
The sum of a list of N numbers is equivalent to the sum of the N-1 first numbers plus Nth number, and the `total` function expresses exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

`int total(int array[14], int n)` is a recursive function yielding the sum of all elements up to index `n`.

```
(array[n] == 1) ?
printf("Bus stop #%d : %d cat\n",(n+1),array[n]):
printf("Bus stop #%d : %d cats\n",(n+1),array[n]);
```

means the same as

```
if (array[n] == 1) {
    printf("Bus stop #%d : %d cat\n",(n+1),array[n]);
} else {
    printf("Bus stop #%d : %d cats\n",(n+1),array[n]);
}
```

expressed using the ternary operator `? :`